# How to extract a Key/Value from a nested array of objects in an array of objects using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following array of object, and I need to extract the name of the object where the url matches 'lll/iii'

I know I can do a .find in a .find and then repeat the inner find but that seems pretty messy. Is there a more elegant solution using es6 or lodash here?

```
[
   {
      "name":"A",
      "Links":[
         {
            "url":"/xxx/yyy"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"B",
      "Links":[
         {
            "url":"zzz/bbb"
         },
         {
            "url":"lll/iii"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think a nested loop is as good as you're going to get here unless you restructure your objects.  To get more of a linear search you would have to have an object of the urls, and then list all of the names that those links are associated with.  This way if you know the url that you are looking for, you can grab that as a constant and then do one iteration to find the name associated with it (as long as each name has unique urls).

Comment: I don't know any existing elegant solutions other than nested `.find`s. Maybe you could make a function that deep finds something like this: `deepFind(arr, 'Links', ({ url }) => url === 'lll/iii')`

Comment: I think Michael's solution is the best. The nested find's are very messy and difficult to understand without effort. I will convert the object to a hash table and then use a simple key/value lookup instead. Thanks for the suggestion.